# Brake pad is gone, piston is leaking brake fluid. Do I have to replace the caliper now too?

Tags: brake-calipers, fluid

Long story short, I waited too long to replace brake pad on my rear wheel. Now it's leaking brake fluid and I was wondering if I have to also replace the caliper along with rotor and brake pad? Or is the caliper still in good condition and will work fine with new pads and rotor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word: **Yes.** Replace the caliper. If it's leaking it ain't working.